# How to interpret the output of deepmask getTopScores function

Tags: lua, computer-vision, deep-learning, torch

I am using facebookresearch's [deepmask](https://github.com/facebookresearch/deepmask) to segment an image. I am trying to modify the [computeProposals.lua](https://github.com/facebookresearch/deepmask/blob/master/computeProposals.lua) module to segment my own images. The key function is getTopProps. In the code block below it is being used to find the masks associated with the top proposals.

```
-- get top propsals
local masks,_ = infer:getTopProps(.2,h,w)
```

The infer class is from the [InferDeepMask.lua](https://github.com/facebookresearch/deepmask/blob/master/InferDeepMask.lua) module. getTopProps returns two things: the masks and the scores. The scores come from the Infer:getTopScores() function.

**Question: How do I interpret the output of the getTopScores function?**

The code comment:

```
-- each line contains: the score value, the scaleNb and position(of M(:))
```

Example output (converted into a numpy array):

```
[[  0.9942829    2.          26.           6.        ]
 [  0.9942829    3.          26.           6.        ]
 [  0.98620307   2.           1.          29.        ]
 [  0.98620307   3.           1.          29.        ]
 [  0.97150999   2.          19.           8.        ]
 [  0.97150999   3.          19.           8.        ]
 [  0.97141284   2.          18.           8.        ]
 [  0.97141284   3.          18.           8.        ]
 [  0.9639107    2.          15.          11.        ]
 [  0.9639107    3.          15.          11.        ]]
```

The first column is clearly a score out of one. What is scaleNb, and what are the positions of M(:)? They are not the pixel locations on the mask.

NB Each mask is of shape (336, 448)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code:

- the score is fairly self-explanatory
- the scaleNb is the index of the adopted scale, i.e. the index `k` in the loop `for k = 1,nScales do` where the table containing the values of the different scales is created by the line `for scale = -3,2,.25 do table.insert(self.scales,scale)`
- M(:) is the tricky part. If I understand the code correctly, `pos` is a tensor containing `nScales` ones, and the `k-th` element of the tensor gets incremented every time an object at scale `k` is selected (they are ordered by score). `temp` (which is the variable that is then used to compute the `x` and `y` values forming what they call `M(:)` is given by the line `local temp=sortedIds[pos[scale]][scale]`.
  What does that contain? It appears to be containing the position of the mask at the scale it has been detected. See the following piece of code:

  `local sc=sc:view(h*w)
  local sS,sIds=torch.sort(sc,true)
  local sz = sS:size(1)
  sortedScores:narrow(2,s,1):narrow(1,1,sz):copy(sS)
  sortedIds:narrow(2,s,1):narrow(1,1,sz):copy(sIds)`

`sortedIds` appears to be containing the `x`,`y` position of the score that is currently being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (but have not proven) that the output is thus:

1. the score value - a value between 0 and 1 describing how good a mask this is.
2. the scaleNb - a value that indicates the rough size of the bounding box used to generate the mask.
3. & 4. position(of M(:)) - some way of relating the position of the bounding box to a smaller version of the original image.